# MySQL query by exact date

Tags: php, mysql, date, blogs

I am querying my database and trying to get blog posts from exactly 1 year ago(more specifically every year to date), the following code should do this according to what I have found but it is instead getting ALL posts in the last year.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts
    WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id' AND post_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    ORDER BY post_date DESC ";
    $result = $dbc->query($sql);
```

What could I do to get exactly one year? I could write a loop to increment the year if I could just figure out querying for exactly one year.

Comment: Use an `=` instead of `>` and `DATE_SUB()`

Comment: This query is correct; as of today 2015-03-16 it would return all posts on or after 2013-03-17. Do you have posts in the year 2015?

Comment: I am creating posts through php my admin, so yes.

Comment: @JayBlanchard like so? "SELECT * FROM posts
        WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id' AND post_date = DATE_SUB() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        ORDER BY post_date DESC "

Answer (score 2):

If this is WordPress, `post_date` is a DATETIME field. So *exactly one year ago* means '2014-03-16 09:03:27'.  I doubt that's what you want. I think you want *on this day last year.*

Try this:

```
     post_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
 AND post date <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

That pair of conditions takes all posts starting at midnight on that day a year ago, up to but not including midnight on the next day.  MySQL implements them with an efficient index range scan.

If you're looking for posts that occurred on this day of the year for any year, you need this sort of expression.

```
      MONTH(CURDATE())      = MONTH(post_date) 
  AND DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) = DAYOFMONTH(post_date)
```

This will not be as fast as my first suggestion because it can't use an index. Also, on leap-dates like '2016-02-29' it will yield odd results.

Answer (score 1):

please try this query

```
  SELECT * FROM posts
        WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id' AND date(post_date) >=date_sub(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
        ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

Comment: This resulted in the same data output, even replacing >= with =.